# Can't evaluate plantuml in org-mode blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have this weird error I don't understand :

```
#+begin_src plantuml :file img/example-uml.png
@startuml
class Example {
- value : Integer
- other : Double
+ up()
+ down()
}
@enduml
#+end_src
```

This fails with a `wrong type argument : char-or-string-p, nil`. It seems to be a problem with the `:file` header arg as using other nonsensical values such as `:file 1` outputs `wrong type argument stringp, 1`.  And `:file "example.png"` outputs `wrong type argument : char-or-string-p, nil` as well. If I remove it, the block complains it has to have a `:file` argument.

[This is the relevant defun](https://pastebin.com/n2nWTLmh) in `ob-plantuml`. But it never uses `char-or-string-p` to validate the arguments. So maybe it's something with the org block ?

I'll add that I have `org-plantuml-jar-path` set properly and that the creation of the image does work in `plantuml-mode`, which is all the more frustrating.

I use emacs 27.1 and org-mode version 9.3.

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Edit : added the backtrace

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument char-or-string-p nil)
  org-babel-execute:plantuml("@startuml\nclass Example {\n- value : Integer\n- othe..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "replace" "file") (:result-type . value) (:results . "replace file") (:exports . "results") (:session . "none") (:cache . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:tangle . "no") (:file . "img/example-uml.png")))
  org-babel-execute-src-block(nil ("plantuml" "@startuml\nclass Example {\n- value : Integer\n- othe..." ((:colname-names) (:rowname-names) (:result-params "file" "replace") (:result-type . value) (:results . "file replace") (:exports . "results") (:file . "img/example-uml.png") (:tangle . "no") (:hlines . "no") (:noweb . "no") (:cache . "no") (:session . "none")) "" nil 4196 "(ref:%s)"))
  org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil)
  call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
  command-execute(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c)
```

Comment: That error message can come from many places. The best thing to do is to `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, repeat the evaluation of the block and post the backtrace that you get. That wil pinpoint the problem much better.

Comment: FWIW, when I evaluate the block with this header: `:file example.png`, everythng works.

Comment: Do you have plantuml installed? That's so weird

Comment: Of course I have plantuml installed, otherwise the evaluation would fail.

Comment: Sure, I don't understand why it'd fail on my install. I'll debug soon.

Comment: @NickD I added the backtrace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119276/discussion-between-nickd-and-nathan-furnal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `org-mode` from 9.3 to 9.4.4 has fixed the issue.